# JQuery concatenate values as they are selected from a dropdown list

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

The idea is that the user selects users from a dropdown list to send them an email.  So when a new user is selected, the email address of that user needs to be concatenated with the others using this format: `'user1@mail.com','user2@mail.com','user3@mail.com'` this format is needed because I use Django and that is the format for the `recipient list`.

Right now I can bring the email address of the user selected using `Ajax` but can´t concatenate in the way I need, this is what I have:

```
forms.py

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    userslist = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = User.objects.filter(here goes my condition to show the users), empty_label='List of users', label='Users', required=False)
    emailaddress = forms.CharField(max_length=1000, label='Send to:', required=False)
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorUploadingWidget(), label="Comment:")
```

Now my Ajax view

```
views.py

class mails(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id_user = request.GET['id']
        us = User.objects.filter(id = id_user)
        data = serializers.serialize('json', us, fields=('email'))
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

And now my JQuery:

```
<script>
    $('#id_userlist').on('change', concatenate);
    function concatenate() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            data: { 'id': id },
            url: '/the_url_to_get_data/',
            type: 'get',
            success: function (data) {
                var mail = ""
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    mail += data[i].fields.email
                    $('#id_emailaddress').val(mail)
                }
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

**How can I concatenate the values in the nedded format?**

If need more info please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.join` to concatenate array elements with a separator. And use `.map` to extract the email from each element of `data`.

```
success: function(data) {
    var mail = data.map(function(el) {
        return el.fields.email;
    }).join(',');
    $("#id_emailaddress").val(email);
}
```

Comment: I tried as you said but didn't work, I think I'm wrong in how I applied your soltion, but I just add this `var orig = $('#id_emailaddress').val(); $('#id_emailaddress').val(orig + mail + ', ');` to my code and work as I need. Thank you so much @Barmar